# ServerSocket port number can be any 5009, 12221,6 785, etc. But why?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I am confused and searched a lot, but couldnt find answer to my question, help me out....

```
ServerSocket s= new ServerSocket(port);
```

from where does this port number comes from?
even if I take any number either of 4 or 5 digits, it works perfectly but why and how?
e.g. port number can be any 5009, 12221, 6785, etc. but why?
and who decides what number it should be?

Comment: It takes a port which is currently available

Comment: but how do we know that which port is available

Comment: Well known port numbers may be found in [RFC 1700](http://support.techedge.com/ports.html).

Comment: @Sadhu: That is only true if you don't specify a port number or for client socket source ports.

Comment: "and who decides what number it should be" - it is teamwork between you and our firewall.

Comment: @trashgod didnt got u ... couldnt get what is written in link u posted

Comment: @Gimby how... if i write a java program for client-server.. i just write any port number.. and it works

Comment: as long as the client and the server use the same port number, it will work.  If the client is a browser, the port is 80.

Comment: Then your firewall is not very restrictive. Which is not necessarily a bad thing. Why do you think it should not work?

Comment: Do you know how TCP/UDP works? I guess not ...

Comment: @Gimby...ya it works...i dont think that it should not work.. but i just wanted to know how it happens..selecting any random port number

Comment: That is just how TCP protocol works, it has little common with strict java actually

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is up to you to specify the listening port for your server side application because the client side has to know to which port it should try connecting to.

As ports range 1-1024 is reserved for system services (this is just by convention, not a rule) you can pick any port from (1024, 65535]. If the port you have selected is occupied by another application, it will just throw an exception. If you do not specify the port number, it will be randomly generated.

Comment: thanks...for ur reply..